# iOS popover collision / conflict

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, popover

The scenario is that a system popover ("AppName Would Like to Use Your Current Location") is replacing an application popover (custom startup message in the app).  The application popover is visible for a split second at startup, but then the system popover appears.

The problem is that when the system popover is dismissed, the custom popover is no longer visible, but many UIViews (e.g. buttons) appear gray, as if there were a popover still presented.

(If the user then causes another popover to be presented, then the missing popovers are presented in sequence after that popover is dismissed.  And then the UIView colors are restored to normal.)

How can I prevent this problem?

Comment: you may need to present your own alert popup _after_ the system's popup has been acknowledged by the end-user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `CLLocationManager` [authorizationStatus](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CLLocationManager/authorizationStatus). If the status is `kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined` then don't show your pop-up because you know the system pop-up is going to show up when you request the user's location. Then you can call `[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]` and wait for the callback in your `CLLocationManagerDelegate` `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:` to show your own pop-up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I chose your answer but then realized that UIAlertView was giving me other problems, and that I should have just used SDCAlertView.  No system alert conflict, no screen freezes, etc.

Comment: Well you should actually be using UIAlertController for iOS 8+ but SDCAlertView is a good alternative.